# Timer to awake Windows System from Sleep after certain time (may be 5 minutes)

Tags: windows-7, sleep, timer

Is for testing my Laptop (Some times it Freeze while going to sleep,Need Hard reboot). Need a solution to test it overnight.

- I set 'Put the computer to Sleep After' to 5 Minutes
- **Now I need a solution to wake it up after 5/10 Minute**s

My Idea is, it should work in a loop.
System is Windows7

Comment: do you have a second machine? have you WOL feature in that machine?.

Comment: Hi @FranciscoTapia Yes it i having WOL , Thanks for the hint, I started my works to implement this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOL(Wake-on-LAN) feature can be use in this scenario as suggested by @Francisco Tapia.